# Unable to embed the facebook timeline to a html website

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

As I see the Page Plugin API for Facebook that is used to embed a FB page on any website, I generated the code from the FB developers site that is as below,

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/SAMatUIS/" data-tabs="timeline" data-width="500" data-height="700" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="false"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/SAMatUIS/" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/SAMatUIS/">Society For Advancement of Management at UIS</a></blockquote></div>
```

But When I put the code and refresh the page, All I am getting is the header of the page but not the timeline. Could anyone help me with this, please?

Screenshot of the result -

[Screenshot of FB page Embed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LXZR.png)

Comment: check out the parent container, maybe it is limited

Comment: It didn't work. Had to use some third-party provider

Comment: so..does it work now? is this question answered? if yes, create an answer and accept it. if not, please add more details - it highly depends on where you added the code.